# Regex search block with size equal to previous block

Tags: regex, fastq

I want to parse FASTQ file with regular expression block by block.
FASTQ file looks like this:

```
@EAS54_6_R1_2_1_413_324     // seqname
CCCTTCTTGTCTTCAGCGTTTCTCC   // seq
+                           // seqname #2
;;3;;;;;;;;;;;;7;;;;;;;88   // qual
@EAS54_6_R1_2_1_540_792     // seqname
TTGGCAGGCCAAGGCCGATGGATCA   // seq
+                           // seqname #2
;;;;;;;;;;;7;;;;;-;;;3;83   // qual
@EAS54_6_R1_2_1_443_348     // seqname
GTTGCTTCTGGCGTGGGTGGGGGGG   // seq
+EAS54_6_R1_2_1_443_348     // seqname #2
;;;;;;;;;;;9;7;;.7;393333   // qual
```

And its format:

```
<fastq>     :=  <block>+
<block>     :=  @<seqname>\n<seq>\n+[<seqname>]\n<qual>\n
<seqname>   :=  [A-Za-z0-9_.:-]+
<seq>       :=  [A-Za-z\n\.~]+
<qual>      :=  [!-~\n]+
```

The problem is that I cant detect end of block (or start of next block) because the `@` is used in `<qual>` block too. But `<qual>` block has to be the same size as `<seq>` block.

**The question: Is it possible to write a regular expression with one group size limited to another group size?**

Like this one (except \2.size token):

```
(?:@([A-Za-z0-9_\.:-]+)\n([A-Za-z\n\.~]+)\n\+([A-Za-z0-9_.:-]*)\n([!-~\n]{\2.size}))*
    ^.....seqname.....^  ^.....seq......^    ^....seqname2....^  ^qual(should be same size as seq)^
```

UPDATE: We can't search for `@` token because it can appear in `<qual>` block

Comment: Regex isn't very good at logic that normally belongs to programming/scripting languages.

Comment: Programming language?

Comment: @ninjalj POSIX regex, or ECMAS

Comment: since FASTQ format is exactly four ordered lines per block, why not just read four lines at a time sequentially and know exactly which line is name, seq, +, and qual? if you already have all the data as a string, split it into an array by '\n', then items 0-3, 4-7, 8-11, etc... are name,seq,+,qual blocks.

Comment: @webb It's not :) As you can see in format `\n` symbol is allowed in `seq` and in `qual` fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, it's not possible to match a{n}b{n} with regex. it requires a context-free grammar; [here's a proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Use_of_lemma).

(instead, just match name, seq, and +, then get [`match.size()`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html) of the seq match, then read the next n characters from the remaining string to get qual.)

Comment: Have you noticed **Is it possible** phrase in question, haven't you? It's NOT a trolling. An answer with proof of impossibility is acceptable.

Comment: @LibertyPaul, please accept my apologies for the false accusation then.

Answer (score 0):

here's a regex to parse it:

```
(.*?(?=\n@[A-Z]|$)) //single-line,global
```

with the `(?=\n@[A-Z]|$)` lookahead, we force `.*?` to grab everything up to *just before* new lines starting with '@' *followed by a (capital) letter*, or end of input

[<kbd>demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/vN3aV0/3)

Comment: It doesn't work properly if first character of `qual` field is `@` https://regex101.com/r/vN3aV0/1

Comment: ahh. but letters can't appear in qual right, so modify the lookahead to see @ + letter? (updated)

Comment: Any symbols between `! ` and `~` (including themselves) + `\n` may appear in qual as mentioned in its regex: `[!-~\n@]+`
https://regex101.com/r/yN9oX6/1

Comment: are seqname always 23 chars, qual/seq 25 ?

Comment: No, `[...]+` means that there could be from 1 to infinity characters. But `qual` length should be same as `seq` length, and I'm trying to find is there any trick in regex which can add this condition.

Comment: that fact alone definitely won't do it. if qual is defined by neither a delimiter nor number of lines, then what pattern is there?

Comment: IDK :) thats why I've asked

Comment: indeed :).  but.  this file presumably exists and *something* knows what to do with it....

Comment: It's an example from `FASTQ` reference site http://maq.sourceforge.net/fastq.shtml
I want to create a C++ parser which will be 100% compatible with `FASTQ`

Comment: just a sprinkle of code logic should be ok though:  `read the id, read to the + (seq) and count the length, substring(remaingInput, whateverLength) = qual`

Comment: It's an obvious solution, but I don't want to write code where it's possible to use something else. Just let `std::regex` understand format and thats it :)